# Can anyone know how to set session in android?

Tags: android

Please tell me can anyone know how set session values in android and how to get value in the android?

Comment: Your question is too vague. What kind of session are you referring to? An HTTP session? Some other kind of session? Try to explain what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I am using app prefs to store state data where necessary.  No sense cluttering up SO with my specifics ... [Keep user state in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150513/keep-user-state-in-android)